# Handcent Next SMS just flagged by Play Protect -- what's going on?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, handcent-sms, play-protect

I've been using **Handcent Next SMS** app for many years. A few moments ago, the Playstore's Play Protect just disabled the app on my phone saying the following:

> This app is fake. It tries to take over your device or steal your data.

The [webpage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.app.nextsms&hl=en_US&gl=US) for the app comes up blank now:

[image]

To my knowledge, 10,000s of people have been using this app for many years.

**Did something just change?**

Anybody have more information about this sudden change/situation??

Comment: not the [first time](https://techaeris.com/2015/06/20/popular-android-app-handcent-sms-suspended-google-playstore) and not [unusual](https://www.indiatimes.com/technology/news/google-sms-scam-apps-ban-552871.html)

Comment: **Note to visitors**: Welcome to a Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Unlike traditional discussion forums, "answers" should only be used to answer the question/explain the situation. While we understand your confusion, please refrain from posting an answer when you have the same issue and only want to inquire about it further. ***Note that this issue is purely between Handcent and Google*. As a community of Android users who don't have any affiliation with them, we do not have access to the matter and can only wait for further official information**. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @AndrewT. Understandable. Where would I keep a look out for such info?

Comment: @theforestecologist mostly the Android news outlets, Android forums, or directly contacting the customer support of Handcent.

Comment: Related on Reddit: [Next SMS removed from google play?](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/to1ss4/next_sms_removed_from_google_play/), [Handcent/nextSMS removed from Play Store?](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidQuestions/comments/tnsavo/handcentnextsms_removed_from_play_store/), [Play store telling me to remove Next SMS, cited as harmful and "trying to take over my phone". Anyone else seen this?](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/to9swa/play_store_telling_me_to_remove_next_sms_cited_as/).

Answer (score 13):

**The Handcent Next SMS app was flagged by Play Protect and taken down from the Play Store on March 26 due to embedding a malicious 3rd-party library and returned on March 30 with an updated, clean version.**

---

#### Timeline

On March 26, according [user223149](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/371073/user223149) while [attempting to reply to this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246037/44325),

> Got this answer from support:
>
> > Our app Handcent Next SMS has been misidentified as malware by Google, we are in talks with Google to get our app back to play store. [...]

Around 1 hour later, this was later confirmed on the official [Handcent website](https://www.handcent.com/), [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/Handcent/status/1507549097288380416), and [Facebook Page](https://www.facebook.com/handcent/posts/2198804186934782),

> Our app Handcent Next SMS has been misidentified as malware by Google, we are in talks with Google to get our app back to play store. [...]

[User 'WildBSinTX' on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/to1ss4/comment/i26xjel/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) sent an email to Handcent support and got a reply,

> I got a reply this morning with an explanation and an attachment with v9.9.9.
>
> *Security patch to fix a potential threat
> *Other fixes to make sure it's in a good safe state
>
> I installed it, and so far, so good.
>
> [...]

Meanwhile, on March 28, Handcent posted an update to the same channels.

[Official site](https://www.handcent.com/)

> We have resolved the issue, together with Google. The app will return to the play store soon. [...]

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/Handcent/status/1508282177926021126)

> We have resolved the issue, together with Google. It usually takes one day or two. [...]. It’s safer and good to go now.

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/handcent/posts/2200406613441206)

> We have resolved the issue, together with Google. The app will return to the play store soon. It usually takes one day or two. [...]. It’s safer and good to go now.

**On March 30, the app was back on the Play Store with v9.9.9.1.**

[The official site](https://www.handcent.com/) also mentions,

> We are pleased to announce that Handcent Next SMS is back to the Google Play . [...]

Handcent also followed up on their social media on March 31.

[Twitter](https://twitter.com/Handcent/status/1509374817752952832)

> Next SMS is now back on the play store, you could go to the play store and install it. [...]

[Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/handcent/posts/2202641403217727)

> Next SMS is now back on the play store, you could go to the play store and install it. [...]

Those who sent an email might also receive a follow-up reply mentioning the app version on the Play Store,

> Next SMS is now back on the play store, you could go to the play store and install it 9.9.9.1. [...]

---

#### Cause

I decided to send an email to Handcent Support and received the v9.9.9 APK file, then also downloaded the APK for v9.9.9.1 after it was published on the Play Store. After decompiling and comparing the content with v9.9.8.6 and v9.9.8.5, one noticeable thing is the removal of `coelib.c.couluslibrary` since v9.9.9 (including v9.9.9.1 from the Play Store).

AppCensus published a blog article written by Joel Reardon on April 6, titled [The Curious Case of Coulus Coelib](https://blog.appcensus.io/2022/04/06/the-curious-case-of-coulus-coelib/). It explained what and how this library worked in detail. Quoting a relevant part about this specific incident,

> #### Disclosure
>
> The following table are the apps that we confirmed communicating with `mobile.measurelib.com`. We reported this issue to Google on October 20th, 2021 along with this list of apps. **They investigated it and removed these and other apps containing the SDK from the Play Store.** [...]
>
> | App Name | Privacy Policy | Installations | phone | email | IMEI | GPS | router SSID | router MAC |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] |
> | [Handcent Next SMS-Text w/ MMS](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.handcent.app.nextsms) | [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20220118151158/https://www.handcent.com/static/%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20ApplicationPrivacyStatement.html) | 1 million+ | no | yes | yes | no | yes | yes |
> | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] | [...] |

<sup>(Emphasis added)</sup>

An article from Android Police published on April 7, titled [Google crackdown kicks a bunch of data-stealing malware off the Play Store](https://www.androidpolice.com/google-play-store-boots-data-harvesting-software-intelligence/) also stated,

> Still, there is some hope for those who have lost income streams from Google's ban. The company may allow some apps to return — as long as they delete the Measurement Systems code. The first few are in fact already back.

Answer (score 3):

Since I did not uninstall the app after the high-risk warning, I was able to go to Play Protect and enable the app. Then I went into settings for the app and changed the permissions to allow for usage of apps that aren't on the Play Store. I also changed the setting where Play Protect wouldn't scan Handcent. Once I restarted, everything was back.