# Handcent Next SMS removed - will it be back? I have info but no rep

Tags: google-play-store

Got this answer from support, but I can't post it as an answer or in comments because I'm a nobody with no reputation:

> Our app Handcent Next SMS has been misidentified as malware by Google,
> we are in talks with Google to get our app back to play store. In the
> meantime, please keep our app and do not uninstall. You should still
> have all your data when it returns to normal. You can use the stock
> app for now. Don't worry, we are trying our best to restore our
> service.

Comment: Hi, I've removed the protection on [that question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/246030/handcent-next-sms-just-flagged-by-play-protect-whats-going-on) for now. Feel free to repost the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, due to the overwhelming amount of low-quality non-answers to that question, it has to be protected again. Let me repost your contribution with credit. Sorry for the trouble and thanks for your contribution.

Comment: thx - a frustrating position to be unable to ask, answer, or even vote! No chance to get out of the reputationless dungeon...